# Converting Daily Snapshots to Ranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse

I have a very large table with years' worth of daily snapshots, showing what the data looks like each day.  For the sake of illustration the table looks something like this:

```
Part   Qty   Snapshot
----   ----  --------
 A       5   1/1/2015
 B      10   1/1/2015
 A       5   1/2/2015
 B      10   1/2/2015
 A       6   1/3/2015
 B      10   1/3/2015
 A       5   1/4/2015
 B      10   1/4/2015
```

I would like to implement a slowly changing data methodology and collapse this data into a form that would look like this (assume current date is 1/4/15)

```
Part   Qty   From      Thru      Active
----   ----  --------  --------  ------
 A       5   1/1/2015  1/2/2015  I
 B      10   1/1/2015  1/4/2015  A
 A       6   1/3/2015  1/3/2015  I
 A       5   1/4/2015  1/4/2015  A
```

I have a function that runs daily so when I capture the latest snapshot, I convert it to this methodology.  This function runs once the data is actually loaded into the table with an active flag of 'C' (current), from the giant table (which is actually in DB2).

This works for me moving forward (once I have all past dates loaded), but I'd like to have a way to do this in one fell swoop, for all existing dates and convert the individual snapshot dates into ranges.

For what it's worth, my current method is to run this function for every possible date value.  While it's working, it's quite slow, and I have several years worth of history to process as I loop one day at a time.

Tables:

```
create table main.history (
  part varchar(25) not null,
  qty integer not null,
  from_date date not null,
  thru_date date not null,
  active_flag char(1)
);

create table stage.history as select * from main.history where false;

create table partitioned.history_active (
  constraint history_active_ck1 check (active_flag in ('A', 'C'))
) inherits (main.history);

create table partitioned.history_inactive (
  constraint history_active_ck1 check (active_flag = 'I')
) inherits (main.history);
```

Function to process a day's worth of new data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main.capture_history(new_date date)
  RETURNS null AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  rowcount integer := 0;
BEGIN

  -- partitioned.history_active already has a current snapshot for new_date

  truncate table stage.history;

  insert into stage.history
  select
    part, qty,
    min (from_date), max (thru_date),
    case when max (thru_date) = new_date then 'A' else 'I' end
  FROM
    partitioned.history_active
  group by
    part_qty;

  truncate table partitioned.history_active;

  insert into partitioned.history_active
  select * from stage.history
  where active_flag = 'A';

  insert into partitioned.history_inactive
  select * from stage.history
  where active_flag = 'I';

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: Where you get the `Active` value on your desire result. And why is only one `B` there?

Comment: Active means it's the most recent record, so each day when new data comes in, that's marked as Active, and all old records are inactive.  It's mostly for people who want to query current data.  There is only one `B` record because the value was 10 for all four days -- it never changed, so we only need one record.